problem when importing file converted from USD to mitsuba XML using blender on sionna: Need triangle mesh
I want to use blender as converter from USD file to sionna compatible file, i.e., mitsuba XML. I installed the mitsuba XML from their official github through add-ons feature.
After I import the USD file to blender and set the triangular face "quad method" as Fixed:

Then,I export with extension Mitsuba (xml).
However, when I load the xml in sionna, I got error that said the Only triangle meshes are supported.
Is there any specific step to convert all collections in blender into triangle mesh so that it can be suitable to sionna.?
any help is really appreciated
Thanks.!
I attach the usd file here:
usd file

You could put all the objects you want to be combined into one exported mesh into a collection and instance it using this method. Then just put a triangulate modifier on that instanced object and export that.

If you want to convert all mesh objects in your scene into triangulated meshes, go to the Outliner and click on the Filter menu (the funnel icon), then in the lower Filter section disable everything except for Objects and Meshes.
Now select all objects thar are shown in the Outliner. Then go to the 3D Viewport, press Tab so all objects switch to Edit Mode. Press A to select all vertices (or edges or faces), then Ctrl+T to triangulate them. Then you can switch back to Object Mode.
By the way, you do not have to filter for mesh objects. You can simply select all objects in the 3D Viewport with A in Object Mode. As long as the active object is a mesh object, all mesh objects will switch to Edit Mode when you press Tab. The explanation above is just to show what you could do with the Filter because in other situations it might be needed to explicitly select only mesh (or other types of) objects.

